# Фильтрация и поиск в InterBase

Tags: sql, interbase

Имеется БД созданная в interbase. Есть таблица `NAZ`. В ней `N_PUNKT` - (города). Скажите какой sql-код написать, что бы осуществить поиск по `N_PUNKT`. Там можно что-то вроде фильтра настраивать? Подскажите как это делается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Вообще смотря какой тип у вашего поля N_PUNKT
SELECT * FROM Naz
WHERE
 N_PUNKT = <SomeValue> 
Возможно такое
 N_PUNKT BETWEEN <SomeValue1> AND <SomeValue2>
Возможно такое
 N_PUNKT LIKE '%<SomeValue>%'
```

Comment: N-PUNKT - varchar канечно.

Comment: К сожалению, фильтры не реагируют ни на between, ни на like. В фильтре можно размещать лишь предложения с операторами сравнения (<, <=, ==) и т.п. Для того, чтобы использовать between или like необходимо соответствующим образом менять CommandText.